# Restoring QCheckBox with Qsettings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qsettings, qcheckbox

Having `QCheckBox` wants to save and restore `checkstate` after closing file.

Tried following but it does not really work!

**The code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class SecondOrder(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondOrder, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 8, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))

        curvaturelabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Nominal curvature')
        stiffnesslabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Nominal stiffness')
        simcurvaturelabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Simplified nominal curvature')   

        self.curvaturecheck = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        self.stiffnesscheck = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        self.simcurvaturecheck = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

        self.clay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.clay.addWidget(curvaturelabel)
        self.clay.addWidget(stiffnesslabel)
        self.clay.addWidget(simcurvaturelabel)

        self.dlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.dlay.addWidget(self.curvaturecheck)
        self.dlay.addWidget(self.stiffnesscheck)
        self.dlay.addWidget(self.simcurvaturecheck)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addLayout(self.dlay, 0, 0)
        grid.addLayout(self.clay, 0, 1)

        Secondorder_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self)
        Secondorder_Group.setTitle("&Second order analysis method")
        Secondorder_Group.setLayout(grid)

        self.elay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.elay.addWidget(Secondorder_Group)     
        self.elay.setSizeConstraint(self.elay.SetFixedSize)

        group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self) 
        group.addButton(self.curvaturecheck) 
        group.addButton(self.stiffnesscheck) 
        group.addButton(self.simcurvaturecheck)

        self.readSettings()

        self.curvaturecheck.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.writeSettings())
        self.stiffnesscheck.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.writeSettings())
        self.simcurvaturecheck.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.writeSettings())

    def readSettings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings('file.ini')
        settings.beginGroup("QCheckBox")
        self.curvaturecheck.setCheckState(settings.value("A", QtCore.Qt.Checked, bool))
        self.stiffnesscheck.setCheckState(settings.value("B", False, bool))
        self.simcurvaturecheck.setCheckState(settings.value("C", False, bool))
        settings.endGroup()

    def writeSettings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings('file.ini')
        settings.beginGroup("QCheckBox")
        settings.setValue("A", self.curvaturecheck.isCheckable())
        settings.setValue("B", self.stiffnesscheck.isCheckable())
        settings.setValue("C", self.simcurvaturecheck.isCheckable())
        settings.endGroup()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SecondOrder()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that following codes are tried, it really saves and restores but it mix multiple checks? wants to be able to check once and restore.

```
    settings.setValue("A", self.curvaturecheck.isChecked())
    settings.setValue("B", self.stiffnesscheck.isChecked())
    settings.setValue("C", self.simcurvaturecheck.isChecked())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to save a type T data then you must use the function that uses type T, in your case you save a boolean with isChecked() and you want to use the function setCheckState() that uses a Qt::CheckState type causing the error.

Considering the above there are 2 solutions:

- Use bool:

```py
def readSettings(self):
    settings = QtCore.QSettings("file.ini")
    settings.beginGroup("QCheckBox")
    self.curvaturecheck.setChecked(settings.value("A", True, bool))
    self.stiffnesscheck.setChecked(settings.value("B", False, bool))
    self.simcurvaturecheck.setChecked(settings.value("C", False, bool))
    settings.endGroup()

def writeSettings(self):
    settings = QtCore.QSettings("file.ini")
    settings.beginGroup("QCheckBox")
    settings.setValue("A", self.curvaturecheck.isChecked())
    settings.setValue("B", self.stiffnesscheck.isChecked())
    settings.setValue("C", self.simcurvaturecheck.isChecked())
    settings.endGroup()
```

- Use Qt::CheckState

```
def readSettings(self):
    settings = QtCore.QSettings("file.ini")
    settings.beginGroup("QCheckBox")
    self.curvaturecheck.setCheckState(
        settings.value("A", QtCore.Qt.Checked, QtCore.Qt.CheckState)
    )
    self.stiffnesscheck.setCheckState(
        settings.value("B", QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, QtCore.Qt.CheckState)
    )
    self.simcurvaturecheck.setCheckState(
        settings.value("C", QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, QtCore.Qt.CheckState)
    )
    settings.endGroup()

def writeSettings(self):
    settings = QtCore.QSettings("file.ini")
    settings.beginGroup("QCheckBox")
    settings.setValue("A", self.curvaturecheck.checkState())
    settings.setValue("B", self.stiffnesscheck.checkState())
    settings.setValue("C", self.simcurvaturecheck.checkState())
    settings.endGroup()
```

It is recommended that you delete the .ini file located in `settings.fileName()`.

On the other hand it is not necessary to use lambda functions, change your code to:

```py
self.curvaturecheck.stateChanged.connect(self.writeSettings)
self.stiffnesscheck.stateChanged.connect(self.writeSettings)
self.simcurvaturecheck.stateChanged.connect(self.writeSettings)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, like your double solutions, both work well :)

Answer (score 1):

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#details

> QButtonGroup provides an abstract container into which button widgets can be placed.. It does not provide a visual representation of this container (see QGroupBox for a container widget), but instead **manages the states of each of the buttons in the group**.

`setValue()` on every checkbox can switch another.

But the real issue is `isCheckable()` (means can be checked or not). Probably you want to use `isChecked()` (value set to true).

EDIT. And you can try to set state by `setChecked()`.

Or if you want to support partially checked use `setCheckState()` (as you used) with `checkState()` to get info.